# how to update the Incremental achievements on google play

Tags: android, google-play-services, achievements

if i got 100 steps like "play the game 100 time" and i played 50 times i can't write like that coz it wont update it till i play 100 times... so how do i update it per game?

```
    if (timePlayed>99) {
            Games.Achievements.unlock(getApiClient(), 
                    getString(R.string.persistant));
        }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, be sure to set the achievement as incremental (with 100 steps) in the Developer Console, as follows:

[image: Developer Console Incremental Achievements]

Next, in your code use the [Games.Achievements.increment()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/achievement/Achievements.html#increment%28com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20java.lang.String,%20int%29) method instead of the `unlock` method.

```
Games.Achievements.increment(getApiClient(), getString(R.string.persistant), 1 );
```

Just replace the last argument (i.e. the `1` in the example above) with the **amount by which to increment**.

That's it, once it reaches the amount you set in the Developer Console the achievement will be unlocked automatically (you do not need to do this manually). Additionally, each time `increment` is called, the percentage in the Achievements screen will be updated to reflect the change in value.

For your purposes, you should call `increment()` once each time the game is started (with an increment value of 1).

Comment: hey, im having a doubt, what if the achievement is unlocked and the app kept incrementing ? :) that wont b a problem i suppose ?

Comment: @faztp12 it is safe to call increment once the achievement is unlocked. It will simply do nothing (as it should) :)